# How to speed up sorted list of files?

Tags: php, performance, sorting, iterator

I have a *FileSystemIterator* which I need to sort.

I use *uaSort* function on `iterator_to_array(new FileSystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS))` with following sorting function:

```
function nameSort($a, $b) {
    if($a->isDir() === $b->isDir()){
        return strNatCaseCmp($a->getFilename(), $b->getFilename());
    }
    return $a->isDir() ? -1 : 1;
}
```

I have 1063 files and directories in *$dir* and *nameSort* gets called 11369-times the list of files is generated in average time of around 6 seconds. I thought additional testing whether item is directory made *uaSort* to call *nameSort* more times but this assumption was wrong because when I removed the lines with *isDir* number of calls raised to 11957. The time it took to run however dropped to 0.6 second.

It looks like calling *isDir* is very slow (it makes the list 10 times slower). How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling `isDir` is so costly, and you are calling it multiple times per path, you might want to cache if something is a dir, and retrieve it from the cache first. This can safe a lot of calls to the `isDir` method.

Comment: When cached it tooks about 1 second, not ideal but quite good.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to get just the contents of a single directory you could use glob.

```
 $file = glob($path."/*", GLOB_MARK);
```

should already be sorted and directories can be identified by tailing / so you can array_filter those out

Comment: I initially wanted to use glob but I like Iterator better because it gives me `SplFileInfo` with all its neat methods. I will try the glob again to test if using functions like is_dir and pathinfo couldn't be faster.

Comment: in this case with the GLOB_MARK flag set you should be able to test for a directory by `substr($file, -1) == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` ,should be less expensive then calling is_dir